# Unable to embed screenshot in Cucumber Report

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I had built a Cucumber framework using Selenium and Java. And I have used maven cucumber reporting plugin for reporting. I am trying to showcase the failed screenshot in the report hence I have added hooks and added conditions to embed the screenshot in the report. Following code, I have written in @After cucumber hooks.

```html
    @After
    public void tearDown(Scenario scenario) throws IOException {
        File file;
        if (scenario.isFailed()) {
            String screenshotPath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\target\\screenshots\\"+scenario.getName()+"\\";
            file = new File(screenshotPath);
            file.mkdir();
            try {
                final File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
                FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File(screenshotPath+"screenshot.png"));

            } catch (final Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String failedScreenShot = screenshotPath+"screenshot.png";
            String url = "<img src="+failedScreenShot+" alt='failed screenshot'>";
            scenario.embed(url.getBytes(),"png", "Click Here To See Screenshot");
        }
    }
```

When the scenario gets failed when executed I am getting error in the report as
[Cucumber Report failed Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgl98.png)

Can someone please help to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

From cucumber 6.0 onward, embed() has been removed [Document/API](https://javadoc.io/doc/io.cucumber/cucumber-java/6.0.0/io/cucumber/java/Scenario.html). So instead of embed(). Use scenario.attach() which accept bytes, you also have to pass the media type and name. This name get displayed in the report.

```
@After
        public void takeScreenShotsOnStepFailure(Scenario scenario) {
            if (scenario.isFailed()) {
                byte[] screenshot = testContext.getAppiumDriver().getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
                scenario.attach(screenshot, "image/png", scenario.getName());
            }
        }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).